# Can bdr only replicate one database per server?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, multi-master, postgresql-bdr

I have installed the new BDR-Solution with PostgreSQL 9.4 and it works like a charm.

**My Problem:** I want to add more databases to the replication but every time if I added the other database and restarted the servers one server is crashing. pg_hba.conf and postgresql.conf are correct.

So I read on [this site](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_User_Guide) that

> "You can replicate just one database from a server"

But on [this site](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/BDR_Comparisons) it sounds like an advantage:

> "You must explicitly configure each database you want to replicate."
>   and "BDR replicates per-database, not per-cluster. So you don't have
>   to split your databases up into different PostgreSQL instances just to
>   control how they replicate."

this sounds to me like I *could* vsync more databases if I want...

Comment: Just FYI, we have some big changes in the pipeline for BDR. In particular configuration is moving from `postgresql.conf` to SQL. You won't need to reconfigure and restart each node to add a new node anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BDR can replicate as many databases per server as you want. You must configure each database separately, that's all.

There is not (currently) any wildcard configuration to say "all databases on the current DB".

A typical configuration looks like:

```
Server1       Server2
DB_A     <=>  DB_A
DB_B     <=>  DB_B
```

Comment: thank you... than i have something other wrong and dont know why it crashes.

Comment: @thisisole Details? Please show full error messages, logs (link to pastebin.com or similar then post the link), configuration files, etc, along with the exact BDR version and how you installed.

Comment: oh man... could hit myself... found out that i have to enter all connections into bdr.connections. my mistake was, that i had multiple bdr.connections-parameter with different entries. so... thank you for your support and one more time: sorry... EDIT: despite they should delete the sentence "You can replicate just one database from a server" from the documentation.

Comment: @thisisole We're revising the docs at the moment, making them part of the source tree not a somewhat out of date wiki. I'll change that to "one or more". In (techincal) English "one" does not imply "one and one"; the point of the statement was that you don't have to replicate all DBs like in normal replication. It wasn't very clear.